# Setup MP3 encoder mft output type failed

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation

I'm now trying to use MP3 encoder mft on Win10 pro Insider preview, but failed to set output media type.

Below is my code:

```
// Fill in MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT data   
MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT mp3wfx;
ZeroMemory(&mp3wfx, sizeof(mp3wfx));
mp3wfx.wID = MPEGLAYER3_ID_MPEG;
mp3wfx.fdwFlags = 2; // no padding
mp3wfx.nBlockSize = int16_t(144 * (128000 / 44100)); // bitrate = 128000kbps
mp3wfx.nFramesPerBlock = 1;
mp3wfx.nCodecDelay = 0;
mp3wfx.wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_MPEGLAYER3;  // MP3 
mp3wfx.wfx.nChannels = 2;
mp3wfx.wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
mp3wfx.wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;
mp3wfx.wfx.nBlockAlign = (mp3wfx.wfx.nChannels * mp3wfx.wfx.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
mp3wfx.wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = mp3wfx.wfx.nSamplesPerSec * mp3wfx.wfx.nBlockAlign;
mp3wfx.wfx.cbSize = sizeof(MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX); // 12

LComObject<IMFMediaType> ciOutputType;  // Output media type of the encoder
hr = fpMFCreateMediaType((IMFMediaType**)(ciOutputType.GetAssignablePtrRef()));
WAVEFORMATEX* pWave = (WAVEFORMATEX*)&mp3wfx;
MFInitMediaTypeFromWaveFormatEx(ciOutputType.get(), pWave, sizeof(MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT));
hr = ciEncoder->SetOutputType(0, ciOutputType.get(), 0);
```

please ignore the wrappers I have on those COM objects/interfaces.
Mftrace output these

```
5552,500 05:05:15.03439 CMFPlatExportDetours::MFTEnumEx @ Activate 00 @034CE628, MFT_FRIENDLY_NAME_Attribute=MP3 Encoder ACM Wrapper MFT;MFT_INPUT_TYPES_Attributes=61 75 64 73 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 01 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 ;MFT_TRANSFORM_CLSID_Attribute={11103421-354C-4CCA-A7A3-1AFF9A5B6701};MFT_OUTPUT_TYPES_Attributes=61 75 64 73 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 55 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 80 00 00 aa 00 38 9b 71 ;MF_TRANSFORM_FLAGS_Attribute=1;MF_TRANSFORM_CATEGORY_Attribute=MFT_CATEGORY_AUDIO_ENCODER
5552,500 05:05:15.03616 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ New MFT @03510D20, <NULL>
5552,500 05:05:15.03618 COle32ExportDetours::CoCreateInstance @ Created {11103421-354C-4CCA-A7A3-1AFF9A5B6701} MP3 ACM Wrapper MFT (C:\Windows\System32\mfcore.dll) @03510D20 - traced interfaces: IMFTransform @03510D20, 
5552,500 05:05:15.03681 CMFTransformDetours::SetOutputType @03510D20 Failed MT: MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND=176400;MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT=4;MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS=2;MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Audio;MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND=44100;MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX=1;MF_MT_USER_DATA=01 00 02 00 00 00 20 01 01 00 00 00 ;MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE=16;MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFAudioFormat_MP3
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND` set to 176400 is apparently not among [defined by standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162907).

Comment: Thanks Roman, I used ciEncoder->GetOutputAvailableType to enumerate all supported output type and got 100 supported types.

Your answer is correct, nAvgBytesPerSec should be bitrate_in_kbps / 8, so in my case, it should be 16000.

Comment: But the strange thing is, although I could enumerate all formats and successfully select one by calling ciEncoder->SetOutputType(0, ciTypeTemp.get(), 0);

If I construct mediatype myself and set all fields to same as the enumerated one, ciEncoder->SetOutputType still fails

Comment: I suppose it's because of `MF_MT_USER_DATA` - it's the part of `MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT` which extends `WAVEFORMATEX` and supposedly you have something there which makes the entire media type incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it says:

```
SetOutputType @03510D20 Failed MT: 
MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE=MEDIATYPE_Audio;
MF_MT_SUBTYPE=MFAudioFormat_MP3; 
MF_MT_AUDIO_PREFER_WAVEFORMATEX=1;
MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND=44100;
MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS=2;
MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE=16;
MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND=176400;
MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT=4;
MF_MT_USER_DATA=01 00 02 00 00 00 20 01 01 00 00 00 ;
```

There are two important things here:

1. `MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND` needs a correct value because there is a list of acceptable bitrates
2. `MF_MT_USER_DATA` is additional format data for the media type; presumably `MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT` values that follow `WAVEFORMATEX` fields - the MFT might expect certain values, which are different from those you provide.

You took the correct approach of asking MFT to enumerate output media types. Now you need to pick the closest and compare to what you have, you should see the difference that makes codec to reject your format.

Comment: Thanks Roman, problem solved.

Used mftrace log to compare failed and succeed case. The only difference is 00 00 20 01 which is 120 vs 00 00 a1 01 which is 417

That's because 144 * (128000 / 44100), just change it to 144 * 128000 / 44100 solves the problem :D